# React native keycloak how to get the redirect uri

Tags: react-native, keycloak

I have implemented the package "react-native-login-keycloak" for react native app. But when I tried to login with the keycloak, it returns an error "Unexpected error when handling authentication request to identity provider". I think its because of the invalid redirect uri. So, where do I get my app uri/redirect uri for the react native app. Any helps appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul, Trying to Answer. Are you looking for the callback url to be exposed from App to return back after Authentication flow or after token flow.

REDIRECT_URI_SCHEME
For Inter-App like Browser of Mobile app to talk to your application

1. **1 Private URI Scheme**
   `YOUR_APP_NAME`://oauth2/redirect  , where YOUR_APP_NAMe could com.orgname.demoapp [ demo is for example]
2. **2 Claimed HTTPS URI Scheme**
   https://`YOUR_APP_NAME`://oauth2/redirect
3. **LoopBack Option**
   http://localhost:/oauth2/redirect [ Problem is the port should be free and not assigned already by anyother application installed in mobile.

Please check below Links
[Some relevant post on the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695213/keycloak-redirecturl-your-redirect-scheme-callback)
[Different URI Schemes](https://blog.pedrofelix.org/2017/10/)