# KEYCLOAK : redirectUrl: '<YOUR_REDIRECT_SCHEME>:/callback'

Tags: react-native, authentication, keycloak

For the part related to the keycloak configuration, what should you put in place of "YOUR_REDIRECT_SCHEME"?

redirectUrl: '<YOUR_REDIRECT_SCHEME>: / callback'

Plus, I get the following error message when I click on the "authorize" button {undifned redirectUrl}

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it would be better if you had provided at least some context about your app, scenario, the setup, etc. so that someone who wants to answer could have some ideas about the problem space. See more at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

But just to respond to your question, I should say that when your app asks an OAuth compatible identity provider (in your case it's Keycloak) for an authorization_code, Keycloak will handle the authentication of the user and after a successful authentication, it will generate the code and should somehow return it to your app (in this case seems your app is a react-native). For mobile apps, you can register a custom URL scheme handler so that whenever a URL with that scheme is going to be opened on the mobile device, the OS asks your app to open that URL and process it. That could be anything like "myapp://".
Then in the redirect URL option in Keycloak, you should define a URL that begins with this custom scheme. The actual URL doesn't matter as long as it's a valid URL format. So when Keycloak tries to redirect the client to that URL, mobile OS will call your handler to process that request and you can get access to parameters that Keycloak has appended to the URL.

I suggest you to read the [OAuth 2 spec for native apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7) for further details.